# How to remove database backups 2 days or older through SQL Server 2005 Integration Service?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a simple Integration Service package which has one `SQL Task` as shown below;

- `WLSTAGE Bakup using Red Gate`: Calls `master..sqlbackup` to backup database

Here is the SQL to run the actual backup

```
exec master..sqlbackup '-E -SQL "BACKUP DATABASE [WLSTAGE] TO DISK = ''\\Backups\<AUTO>'' WITH COMPRESSION = 1, INIT, MAILTO = ''<left blank intentionally>'', VERIFY"'
```

Since I have specified the backup file name as `<AUTO>`, **I am wondering if there is a simple way to remove backups older than 2 days** (if possible, without having to write any plumbing code to parse the file name).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the AUTO statement does, but you are probably aware of the Maintenance Cleanup task.  Does it not do what you need?

I like powershell for things like this as well.

```
(get-item -path "d:\perflogs\*" | where {$_.creationTime -lt ((get-date) - (new-timespan -days 30))} | where {$_.extension -eq ".blg"}) | remove-item
```

Comment: @Sam: Specifying `<AUTO>` creates a file name dynamically using parent's directory name and current date stamp - Back to the main point, is it possible to call powershell scripts within SSIS package as you have suggested?

Comment: I suppose it would be a command line call you could put in a job step.  Did you try the Maintenance Cleanup task?

Comment: Thanks Sam, I have decided to use PowerShell in `Execute Process Task` mentioned in this StackOverflow answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070050/powershell-in-ssis/1070088#1070088

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  I might consider a .net script task solution as well, to keep all the code in one place. I think you can run powershell from inside .net as well, so the .net would just be a bit of a wrapper.